# How to create elements on behalf of an given number?

Tags: xslt

A normal order has orderlines. A pre order has no orderlines but does tell me how many I could expect te receive. The application that is receiving the orders can handle orders with orderlines. Because we are now also using pre orders I'd like to create the same amount of empty orderlines that's in the pre order so the application can accept the edi.

I've already created a check to see if its a order with orderlines or a pre order.

Example incoming code, in this case 'amount 3' means there should be 3 order lines:

```
<WarehouseOutboundOrder>
    <Amount>3</Amount>
    <OrderDate>27-05-2019 13:22</OrderDate>
    <CreationReason>E01_NEW_PREORDER</CreationReason>
</WarehouseOutboundOrder>
```

Expected outgoing code:

```
<WarehouseOutboundOrder>
    <Amount>3</Amount>
    <OrderDate>27-05-2019 13:22</OrderDate>
    <CreationReason>E01_NEW_PREORDER</CreationReason>
    <WarehouseOutboundOrderLine>
        <Quantity></Quantity>
        <Description></Description>
    </WarehouseOutboundOrderLine>
    <WarehouseOutboundOrderLine>
        <Quantity></Quantity>
        <Description></Description>
    </WarehouseOutboundOrderLine>
    <WarehouseOutboundOrderLine>
        <Quantity></Quantity>
        <Description></Description>
    </WarehouseOutboundOrderLine>
</WarehouseOutboundOrder>
```

How can I achieve this using xslt?

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0? -- P.S.Please post your current attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Yes it does support XSLT 2.0. This is a unique situation, normally I only change or update xslt's that already do what I want them to do (once I've found them here). I've never made anything like this and can't find anything similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="WarehouseOutboundOrder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to Amount">
            <WarehouseOutboundOrderLine>
                <Quantity/>
                <Description/>
            </WarehouseOutboundOrderLine>        
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfM

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's exactly what I need. I've up-voted your post (Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.). I use a program that generates xslt's, this is custom work that it can't generate. I only edit small pieces of code to create what I need.